# Programmatically observing changes in Recoil with React

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I'm using Recoil (recoiljs.org) in my react project.

I have a fairly classic setup with a list of items - the object graph looks something like this:

```
Routes - routes is an array of Route objects
- Route - route object is edited in a form
```

I use an atom to represent the currently selected Routes array, e.g.

`const [routes, setRoutes] = useRecoilValue(currentRoutesViewState);`

And I also use a `selectorFamily` to allow individual controls to bind to and update the state of an individual item.

```
const routeSelectorFamily = selectorFamily({
  key: "routeSelectorFamily",
  get:
    (routeKey) =>
    ({ get }) => {
      const routes = get(currentRoutesViewState);
      return routes.find((r) => r.key === routeKey);
    },
  set:
    (routeKey) =>
    ({ set }, newValue) => {
      set(currentRoutesViewState, (oldRoutes) => {
        const index = oldRoutes.findIndex((r) => r.key === routeKey);
        const newRoutes = replaceItemAtIndex(
          oldRoutes,
          index,
          newValue as RouteViewModel
        );
        return newRoutes;
      });
    },
});
```

As you can see, the `set` function allows someone to update an individual route state and that is replicated up into anything rendering routes.

However, I would like to auto-save any changes to this whole graph but don't know how to easily observe any changes to the Routes parent object. Is there a way to programmatically subscribe to updates so I can serialize and save this state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a `useEffect` for that:

```
const currentState = useRecoilValue(currentRoutesViewState);

useEffect(() => {
  // currentState changed.
  // save the current state
}, [currentState])
```

Comment: Interesting, this is a good idea. I assume this will fire at least once on mount whether the value has changed or not - so I'd need to track calls to this method somehow right - to know for sure if the state has changed?

Comment: That is correct, the `useEffect` will run once at component mount. You could add a state acting as a flag called `didUpdate` or `isDirty` and set it to true the first time it runs and check the flag to save the current state.